# ufw and systemctl command is not working inside docker container

Tags: docker

I have to start some service using systemctl using dockerfile. dockerfile contains ufw allow command that is also failing

```
ufw error:
56.90 WARN: initcaps
56.90 [Errno 2] iptables v1.8.4 (legacy): can't initialize iptables table `filter': Permission denied (you must be root)
56.90 Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.

systemctl error: ( I dont want to use service command)
57.16 System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
57.16 Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
57.16 System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
57.16 Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

My requirement:
I can only run docker build from my side and i have to use ufw and systemctl
with docker run i know about --privileged flag but as i have mentioned i can only access to dockerfile and run dockerbuild

Comment: You can't run either `ufw` or `systemctl` from inside a container.  There are tricks to make `systemctl` possible, but it's usually not a best practice.  Docker itself maintains the network environment for a container and you can't usually set independent container-level firewall rules.

Answer (score 0):

You can't give privileged mode in Dockerfile. You can only run by --privileged when start docker container.